# Unable to add an empty array to a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I would like to fill a dictionary with 3 empty arrays, I am using this code:

definition:

```
var items: [String:[SomeRecord]] = [:]
```

code:

```
self.items["1"] = []
self.items["2"] = []
self.items["3"] = []
```

"items" seems to remain empty after the 3 assignments. Any idea?

Comment: Because you're modifying `self.items` instead of `items`?

Comment: the 3 lines of code are in a method of class

Comment: `"items" seems to remain empty after the 3 assignments` how did you check? checking count?

Comment: You need to post more context. Most likely you're modifying a different object from the one you're later observing.

Comment: Try `print("\(self.items.count)")` and see what you get.

Comment: I see your code work fine

Comment: It does work OK. Apparently the debugger seems to see it as empty, but print writes "3" as expected.

Comment: I currently tested your code, it seems to be OK.... I have 3 assigments (3 empty arrays)

Comment: You can check the work of this in playground and it works fine. I guess, the debugger cannot define how to show `SomeRecord` in the debug panel

Comment: Thanks @alex, my problem now is adding items to the empty arrays. It seems like getting the array from the dictionary and adding an item for it doesn't really add the item in the dictionary.

Comment: @bashan,Please edit your question and show the code how you getting the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to add empty arrays to a dictionary of arrays. You can double-check that your dictionary indeed contains entries for keys `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`:

```
struct SomeRecord {
    var myRecord : String
}

class MyClass {

    var items: [String:[SomeRecord]] = [:]

    init() {
        self.items["1"] = []
        self.items["2"] = []
        self.items["3"] = []
    }
}

var myInstance = MyClass()

// simple check
print(myInstance.items.count) // 3

// detailed check
for (key, value) in myInstance.items {
    print("key: \(key), value: \(value)")
}
/* key: 2, value: []
   key: 1, value: []
   key: 3, value: []  */

// appending to empty array: OK
myInstance.items["1"]?.append(SomeRecord(myRecord: "record1.1"))
print(myInstance.items.count) // 3

// adding items to dictionary: OK
myInstance.items["4"] = [SomeRecord(myRecord: "record4.1")]
print(myInstance.items.count) // 4
```

Note above that the `.self` prefix is redundant in the initializer unless you make use of parameter to or a local variable in the initializer named `items`. So in this simple example above, `.self` can be omitted.